# Neovim Gray Background

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, iterm2

#### Problem

Anytime I switch to a colorscheme the background turns this ugly gray that gives everything a washed out look. Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Example screenshot—

[image: Dracula scheme]

#### More details

This does not appear to happen when using [`agude/vim-eldar`](https://github.com/agude/vim-eldar).

The `:hi` reports are below for vim-eldar—

```
:verbose hi Normal Normal xxx         guifg=White guibg=Black
    Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-eldar/colors/eldar.vim
```

and Dracula—

```
:verbose hi Normal Normal xxx         ctermfg=255 ctermbg=236 guifg=#F8F8F2 guibg=#282A36
    Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim/colors/Dracula.vim
```

#### Attempts

I've tried the following two things but no luck:

1. make sure terminal color is set to xterm-256 color
2. `:set background=dark`

My iTerm2 color preset is `dark background`—

[image: iTerm2 prefs]

Comment: That looks like Dracula in the screenshot. Is it *only* happening then, or with other colorschemes as well? What is the background color of your terminal emulator ?

Comment: Other schemes as well

Comment: That looks like macOS terminal, am i correct? Ive not had this problem recently. Have you tried [debugging your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) ?

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose hi Normal` before and after the switch?

Comment: Another possibly important clue: I found a schema where this is not taking effect. `  Plug 'agude/vim-eldar'` Specifically looked for a high contrast theme to test this.

Comment: before:
`:verbose hi Normal
Normal         xxx guifg=White guibg=Black
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-eldar/colors/eldar.vim`

Comment: after `:verbose hi Normal
Normal         xxx ctermfg=255 ctermbg=236 guifg=#F8F8F2 guibg=#282A36
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim/colors/Dracula.vim`

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble

Comment: Is that iTerm2 then ? Because it supports truecolor (as does neovim); could have something to do with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76908/discussion-between-david-ben-knoble-and-maxwell).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## A quick rundown on colorschemes

See `:help :colorscheme`. Essentially it sources a file containing `:highlight` commands.

### What are highlight commands?

Statements of the form

```
:hi[ghlight] [default] {group-name} {key}={arg} ..
```

that highlight sections of code (when syntax highlighting is enabled with `syntax enable`) and sections of the UI.

They can set special attributes like *italics*, colors, and even the foreground and background.

### What is this background stuff ?

More than likely, it comes from a colorscheme using the `Normal` highlighting group (`:help :hi-normal-cterm`).

Essentially, [as mentioned in the chat conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44362236#44362236), some colorschemes do something like `:hi Normal ctermbg=...` to change the color of the background of the terminal inside vim. This was happening for Dracula (and, as you noticed, it's not pretty. More on that in a second), and [Molokai as well](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44361208#44361208).

## How do I fix it?

I'm going to address this on a case-by-case basis, then give some broader options.

#### Dracula

It came up in the chat that the OP was using Dracula. As I mentioned [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44361786#44361786), during a [theme overhaul](https://github.com/dracula/vim/pull/62) some [issues](https://github.com/dracula/vim/issues/65) were [raised](https://github.com/dracula/vim/issues/69) about the theme background.

It was using a 256-color *approximation* of the right color when it couldn't use truecolor (like a GUI hexcode). We [added in a way to disable this](https://github.com/dracula/vim/blob/b34882be6ccca2cd795346be3ed4d35c3e4e7cf1/doc/dracula.txt#L76), restoring the terminal background color.

Put this

```
let g:dracula_colorterm = 1
```

before `colorscheme dracula` to use your own terminal background.

#### Molokai

The OP also wanted to adjust `molokai`. After discussing a bit, it was decided that molokai too looked good with no colored background. The solution is to use an autocommand to modify the colorscheme, like so:

```
au ColorScheme molokai hi Normal ctermbg=None
```

(As always, I suggest wrapping autocommands in an augroup—see `:help augroup`).

### General Case

The next piece of discussion was, "Can this be done for *every* colorscheme?"

The answer is, **yes**. Furthermore, you can customize *any* colorscheme, with *any* highlighting group, using this technique.

For example, to disable background highlighting on all colorschemes, use

```
au ColorScheme * hi Normal ctermbg=None
```

## Conclusion

Colorschemes are hard. But like everything else, they are customizable. Sometimes it helps to see if they have documentation; other times, check the GitHub repos and consider filing an issue. Further recourse includes customizing the scheme using autocommands.

At the end of the day, the colors we stare at while we code matter! Don't let them hurt your eyes.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me, and it was because I configured my colorscheme colors *after* I actually set the colorscheme. Moving my `colorscheme` command to a line after the actual color configuration solved my problem.